# Convergence of sequence of stopped partial sums to functional of Wiener process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

I asked the same question on [stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724956/convergence-of-stopping-time-to-that-of-standard-wiener-process?noredirect=1#comment5625799_2724956) (with less details) and decided to post it here. Hopefully it's close to the research level.

**Preliminary**: I have a sequence of normalized partial sum processes $\{X_n(t): 0 \leq t \leq 1\}$ with the form
$$
X_n(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \xi_i
$$
Here $\{ \xi_i \}$ needs not be i.i.d. (since I am dealing with time series data), but I think it's not that instrumental here. Anyway, I managed to apply some functional central limit theorem to obtain
$$
X_n \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} W
$$
in the Skorohod space $D[0,1]$, where $W$ is a standard Wiener process.

**Main Setting**: Let $0 < l < u < 1$ and $c > 0$ be fixed constants. Define the stopping times
$$
\tau_n = \inf \{l \leq t \leq u: X_n(t) > c \} \wedge u
$$
I would like to show weak convergence of the stopped partial sum processes $\{ X_n(\tau_n) \}$. Initially I guessed the limit is $W(\tau)$ with
$$
\tau = \inf\{l \leq t \leq u: W(t) > c \} \wedge u
$$
By virtue of Skorohod representation theorem we may just take the convergence as holding almost surely. Also since $W$ is continuous, we may just use the uniform metric $d(x,y) = \sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} |x(t) - y(t)|$ to simplify the problem.

However, after thinking for a while I realized that $X_n(\tau_n)$ needs not converge to $W(\tau)$. The problem I see is that we may well conceive the case where $W$ attains $c$ at some $t_0 < u$ but does not exceed $c$ on the whole compact interval $[l, u]$. In particular, let $W(u) < c$. By definition we have $\tau = u$. But in this case we may modify $X_n$ around $t_0$ to make them exceed $c$, so that $\tau_n$ would approximate $t_0$ rather than $\tau$, and $X_n(\tau_n)$ would approximate $c$ rather than $W(\tau) = W(u) < c$.

**Question**: As said, I desire a weak convergence of $X_n(\tau_n)$ (I don't need closed-form of the limiting distribution function, as long as I can approximate it by means of Monte Carlo). Is it possible to show weak convergence of $X_n(\tau_n)$ (possibly to another limit than the one conjectured above) with the given information? Otherwise, what conditions could I impose (preferably on $\{ \xi_i \}$) to enforce the weak convergence?

Any suggestion and pointer to reference would be more than welcome!

Comment: It seems to me that the case that worries you can only happen when $\sup_{t \in [l,u]} W(t) = c$, which occurs with probability zero.  So it shouldn't be an obstacle to showing $X_n(\tau_n) \to W(\tau)$ almost surely (after Skorohod).

Comment: Following on Nate's comment, you might want to use the fact that if measures $\mu_n$ converge weakly to a measure $\mu$ and $A$ is a set whose boundary is a $\mu$-null set, then $\mu_n(A)$ converges to $\mu(A)$. Bogachev's "Measure Theory" monograph has a proof of this somewhere.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's a very helpful hint, thanks! Now the remaining part is simple to prove.